Does changing the grid-row will changes the grid-column value to 1/2? (CSS)
My main question there is in the title, here I will ask my question in the following example:
CSS and HTML codes:


*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.panel{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr;
    background-color: aqua;
    height: 100vh;
    gap: 15px;
}

.panel-a{
    background-color: brown;
}

.panel-b{
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.panel-c{
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Grid</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="temp-style.css"/>

</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-a">A</div>
        <div class="panel-b">B</div>
        <div class="panel-c">C</div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>



the result of these codes are normally! But when I add the grid-row: 1/2; code to panel-b class, an unexpected thing happens:
Item B goes to the first column! Why?! Have we changed the grid-column value? NO!! so why goes to the first column?

because the browser will first place the B element and then A

I added a few related duplicates so you understand the placement algorithm and how it works

@TemaniAfif That means: very briefly answer of my main question(in the title) is YES?

it's not a yes, it's "you need to understand the algorithm". a simple "yes" will give you wrong assumptions and you will get even more lost. There is a logic that you need to understand

After studying and partially understanding the relevant algorithm, the short answer to my main question is: No! Because the grid-column value does not change! but, the algorithm works in such a way that the item whose grid-row is determined is placed first.
